# correct use of subqueries with mysql

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have this 3 tables in my DB: `product (id, sku, type, price)`, `product_relation (parent_id, child_id)` and `product_stock (product_id, quantity, in_stock)`. There are possible relations between products: Product of type X can be a parent (can consists of) to several products of type Y (relation kept in `product_relation` table). In DB products of type X always have quantity set to 0. Now here is the thing. I need to get only products (`sku` and `id`) of type X which are in stock (`in_stock = true`) and at least one of their children has `quantity > 0` or `in_stock = true`.

I'm stuck on that for several hours. I can't make a good query for this. The closest one I achieved is

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`sku` FROM `product` AS a 
INNER JOIN `product_stock` AS b 
ON a.`id` = b.`product_id`
INNER JOIN `product_relation` AS c 
ON c.`child_id` = b.`product_id` 
WHERE b.`in_stock` = 1 AND a.`type` = 'X'
```

but it's not good, because many items are missing. I don't know if this can be handle by joins only or subqueries have
Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understood what you were asking; does this help?

```
SELECT a.id, a.sku 
FROM product AS a 
    INNER JOIN product_stock AS b  ON a.id = b.product_id
WHERE b.in_stock = 1 AND a.type = 'X'
and exists (
    SELECT 'EXISTS'
    FROM product d
        INNER JOIN product_relation AS c ON c.child_id = d.product_id
    WHERE 
        c.product_id = a.product_id
        AND (d.quantity > 0 or d.in_stock = true)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a sub query if you don't want it. The advantage here is that if you wanted to know which children met the criteria you could just add its fields to the select clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.`id`, parent.`sku`


FROM
`product` parent as parent
INNER JOIN `product_relation` AS c 
ON c.`parent_id` = b.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `product_stock` AS parent_stock
ON p.`product_id` = parent_stock.`product_id`    
INNER JOIN `product` as child 
ON c.`child_id` = child.`product_id`
INNER JOIN `product_stock` AS child_stock
ON c.`product_id` = child_stock.`product_id`    

WHERE parent_stock.`in_stock` = 1
    and (child_stock.`in_stock` = 1 or child_stock.`quantity`> 0)
    and  parent.`type` = 'X'
```